# Tube slowly loses air

Tags: innertube

A few weeks ago I noticed that my bike tube slowly leaked out air over the course of a day or 2. I bought a new tube and it does the same thing. I checked in water and saw no leaks.

Comment: Likely the valve -- it may not be screwed tightly.  Or these are ultra-thin hoity-toity tubes and not intended to hold air for more than about 48 hours.

Comment: I checked the valve and didnt see any bubbles, as for the tube its a https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BHV6NDR/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_awdo_t1_fkm0Cb4R5KFQG

Comment: Can you say how much pressure you lost over that time? All tubes do leak air. Butyl tubes, which are almost all tubes, should leak them pretty slowly indeed. I've generally needed to refresh my wife's tire pressure slightly every week (adding about 5 PSI). I think light butyl tubes should leak a bit faster. Latex, which I use on my road bike, does leak significantly faster, but I need to add about 5 PSI per day.

Comment: You do know how to use a Presta valve, right?

Comment: Ok so I am losing all the air or almost all the air over 24 hours. My front tire does not have this problem. My new and old tube for back tire have this problem

Comment: OK. You earlier commented you "checked the valve and didn't see any bubbles". I assume you submerged the tube in water. Did you check the whole tube, or just the valve? If the latter, you should check the whole tube. The amount of pressure you're losing is consistent with a slow leak. I've had these before, and you will see a stream of small bubbles if you move the tube slowly.

Comment: Is your rim tape in good condition? Did you check your rim for sharp edges and your tire for any pieces of glass/metal before installing the new tube? Are there any sharp edges on the valve hole(rim)?

Comment: Get a tube from a different manufacturer as some are really bad quality. Also, you may get a tube with a removable valve core and fill some 10-15cc of tubeless tyre sealant into the tube. I've been doing this for a while. The tyres stay inflated for a longer time and are less vulnerable to tiny punctures.

Comment: I had a similar tricky loss of air.  I had to put a fair bit of pressure in to even see bubbles underwater.  They turned out to be coming from under the edge of an old patch - somehow one side wasn't properly stuck down but had worked for months. That's the first time I've had a patch fail after a delay.

Comment: Note that when you check the tube for leaks in a tub of water you should first inflate it so that it balloons out to about half again its normal diameter.

Comment: I checked the whole tube undet water and cant find this tube size from another manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

9/10 it’s a tiny sharp object like a sliver of wire stuck in the tire. Take the tube out of the tire, pump it up really big, run the tube through your hand until you feel where the air is coming out. Then look at the tire in that spot and find the thing that poked a hole in the tube.

Alternatively, switch to tubeless and don’t worry about small punctures anymore.

Comment: Do not run the tyre through your air if you suspect something sharp, check it visually first. You can injure yourself with something rusty or otherwise ugly. It cn be surprisingly large. Check it visually. Compare the leak position on the tube with the corresponding place on the tyre, remember the valve position on the tyre.

Comment: Yes. That’s what I meant. Tube, not tire. Oops.